# make date() return a timezone-specific date/time without using date_default_timezone_set()

Tags: php

Is there a way to use the `date()` function and have it return the a specific Timezone's current date, and not the server date?

I understand I can use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
date('j F Y');
```

however, I am doing this in the context of a large application, and doing the `date_default_timezone_set()` might make the other date operations in the rest of the script behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (>= 5.3.0), which allows you to set the timezone for the given date. This will allow you to modify the timezone for only a given date, and not dates that may appear elsewhere in your script.

> Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified
>   format.

**Object oriented style**

```
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone timezone ] )
```

**Procedural style:**

```
DateTime date_create_from_format ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

The docs do a good job of providing the details of each parameter if you are unfamiliar with them so I will refrain from posting it all.

Another alternative would be to modify the timezone in the [`date format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). The timezone identifier was (added in PHP 5.1.0).

Comment: This looks great, however docs say that DateTime::createFromFormat needs PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, but our PHP version is PHP 5.2.17. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use [date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) then.  The timezone identifier was (added in PHP 5.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead, it allows you to specify the timezone on creation (default is UTC), or by using `setTimezone()` to change the rendering timezone.